# Problem with on change persist after i choose a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

Good morning everyone.
I'm working on a project and i have to resolve a problem.

[image]

as you can see "formulario" is a mandatory variable indeed if we try to click to "Prossimo step" (Next step) this is the result:

[image]

he said select a form to continue. 
But if we chose a form the error persist:

[image]

So i thought the problem was on change function but when i modified the code never changed.

this is the function:

```js
$('#first-step-button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!$('#formulario').val()) {
            $('select#formulario').parent().addClass('error-control-group').on('change', function() { $(this).removeClass('error-control-group') });
            return false;
        } else if(!$('#variable').val()){
            $('select#variable').parent().addClass('error-control-group').on('change', function() { $(this).removeClass('error-control-group') });
            return false;
        }
        $('.collapse').collapse("show");
        $('#first-step-button').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.row .second-step').removeClass('second-step');
    });
```

This is the html code

```html
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <label for="formulario" class="control-label no-padding-right bolder blue"><?= $this->translate('Select form to test on'); ?>: *</label>
                <select class="chosen-select form-control" name="formulario" id="formulario" data-placeholder="<?= $this->translate('Select the form'); ?>">
                    <option></option>
                    <?php foreach($this->formulario_list as $f): ?>
                        <option <?php if($f->formulario == $this->formulario): ?> selected <?php endif; ?> value="<?= $f->formulario; ?>"><?= $this->translate($f->formulario); ?> - <?= $this->translate($f->titolo); ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <p class="error-msg alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> <?= $this->translate('Select a form to continue'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

PHP

```
$deModel = $this->getModelObject('Datawide\Model\DataExtractionTable', 'data_extraction');
    $formularioList = $deModel->getListaFormulari($categorieUtente);
    $formularioListArray = $deModel->getListaFormulari($categorieUtente)->toArray();

$view = new ViewModel(array(
        'normal_user' => $checkUE['normal_user'],
        'formulario_list' => $formularioList,
        'formulario_list_array' => $formularioListArray,
        'var_list' => $varList
    ));
    return $view;



if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            $formulario = $this->getRequest()->getPost('formulario');
```

Comment: Please show your full relevant code and try to create an example if you can

Comment: `This is the html code` I'm sorry but I see PHP in your `html`. As I said, please post only RELEVANT code, create a minimal example of your problem, do some effort so people would help you. Also you're not showing any PHP as to where the error is being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing the on change to the parent element and not the select element. add this to your code instead

```
$('#formulario').on('change', function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('error-control-group');
});
```